# multiple columns validation

Tags: list, column, validation

I have 3 columns, column1 and column2 are Date type, column3 is choise. Now I need create list validation like this:

1. column2 can be empty or not older than column1

and

2. when column2 is not empty than column3 cannot be empty and conversely

I created this, but it doesn't work:(

=AND(OR(ISEMPTY([COLUMN2]);([COLUMN2]>=[COLUMN1]));AND([COLUMN2]<>"";(NOT(ISBLANK([COLUMN3])))))

Comment: Thaks a lot for reply. I found the blog below, but after used it, it didn't work. So I used validation from M.Harrelson (thank), but when I filled out column2 in right date, I couldn't fill out column3. So I start to test it in Excel and here is my validation: =and((if(and(column2<>"",column3<>""),true,and(column2="",column3=""))),(if(column2>=column1,true,isblank(column2))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here: http://info.summit7systems.com/blog/part-2-how-to-conditionally-require-data-in-more-than-one-sharepoint-column

I modified the formula on that page as follows:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(column3)=TRUE,column2<>""),FALSE,
IF(OR(ISBLANK(column2),column2>=column1)=TRUE,TRUE,FALSE))
```

The first part checks whether column3 is blank and column2 has a value, and the second part checks that column2 is either blank or not earlier than column1.

Comment: So following @Danny '365CSI' Engelman 's logic, this can be shortened to a single if:
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(column3),column2<>""),FALSE,OR(ISBLANK(column2),column2>=column1)) or to just a logical:
=AND(OR(AND(column2<>"",column3<>""),column2=""),OR(ISBLANK(column2),column2>=column1))

Answer (score 0):

Logical Functions return TRUE/FALSE

So

```
ISBLANK(column3)=TRUE
```

equals

```
 ISBLANK(column3)
```

and

```
IF(OR(ISBLANK(column2),column2>=column1)=TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)
```

equals

```
OR(ISBLANK(column2),column2>=column1)
```